# Ubuntu freezes on boot after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Upgraded from 12.04 through the other releases to 14.04.  Got message that everything was fine.

Restarted machine.  Took a long time.  Finally came up.  Cursor was frozen.  After a minute, the screen went into a lined pattern.  Waited five minutes, nothing changed.  Turned off machine, tried again.  Same result.

Ubuntu 12.04 was running perfectly before the upgrade.

I have a separate Windows 7 machine, so I'm not locked-out of the internet.

I'd like to be able to get a new install of 14.04, but I don't see how I can if the screen is messed up and the cursor won't respond.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Barry

Answer (score 1):

You can try booting 14.04 off a USB stick as a live session. If that gets you a working display, a fresh install from the same USB stick should just work.

If it doesn't boot up a workable live session, you need to give more information about the hardware, like video card type etc.